# How to prove the necessary conditions for checking the positive semidefiniteness of a $2$ by $2$ matrix?

Tags: matrices, quadratic-forms, positive-semidefinite

How to prove that the following conditions are necessary and sufficient for checking the positive semidefiniteness of a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$?

$$ a_{11}\geq 0, \qquad a_{22}\geq 0, \qquad a_{11}a_{22} \geq a_{21}^2 $$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yes

Comment: yes that is right

Comment: How to prove that if these conditions are met then no eigen value can be negative

Comment: This is [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion). There should be proofs in many books.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo they are for general $n\times n$ matrices. I am interested in $2\times 2$ matrices. I just want to understand a simpler proof.

Comment: *Mathematics of Nonlinear Programming* by Peressini et al. gives a proof for $2\times 2$ matrices, if you would like a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a symmetric matrix
$$
A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a_{11}&a_{12}\\
a_{12}&a_{22}
\end{array}
\right).
$$
$A$'s being positive semi-definite is defined as for all
$$
\mathbf{x}=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\
x_2
\end{array}
\right),
$$
it satisfies
$$
\mathbf{x}^{\top}A\mathbf{x}\ge 0\iff a_{11}x_1^2+2a_{12}x_1x_2+a_{22}x_2^2\ge 0.
$$

### Necessity

Fix $x_2=0$, and the equality reduces to
$$
a_{11}x_1^2\ge 0.
$$
This leads to
$$
a_{11}\ge 0.
$$
Similarly, fixing $x_1=0$ would lead to
$$
a_{22}\ge 0.
$$

To show that $a_{11}a_{22}\ge a_{12}^2$, let us first show that, e.g., $a_{12}=0$ as long as $a_{22}=0$. In fact, if $a_{22}=0$, the inequality reduces to
$$
a_{11}x_1^2+2a_{12}x_1x_2\ge 0.
$$
If $a_{12}\ne 0$, the arbitrariness of $x_2$ would have this last inequality violated. Hence it is a must that $a_{12}=0$. Thanks to this result,let $x_1=a_{22}$ and $x_2=-a_{12}$, and the inequality becomes
$$
a_{11}a_{22}^2+2a_{12}a_{22}\left(-a_{12}\right)+a_{22}a_{12}^2\ge 0,
$$
or equivalently,
$$
a_{22}\left(a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}^2\right)\ge 0.
$$
If $a_{22}\ne 0$, the above inequality gives
$$
a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}^2\ge 0;
$$
if $a_{22}=0$, as is proven from above, $a_{12}=0$, and
$$
a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}^2=0\ge 0.
$$
Thus $a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}^2\ge 0$ unconditionally.

### Sufficiency

We shall show that
$$
a_{11}x_1^2+2a_{12}x_1x_2+a_{22}x_2^2\ge 0
$$
holds for all $x_1$ and $x_2$, as long as
$$
a_{11}\ge 0,\quad a_{22}\ge 0,\quad a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}^2\ge 0.
$$

If $a_{11}=0$, the three constraints reduce to
$$
a_{22}\ge 0,\quad a_{12}=0,
$$
which gives
$$
a_{22}x_2^2\ge 0.
$$
Thus the desired inequality holds true when $a_{11}=0$.

When $a_{11}\ne 0\iff a_{11}>0$, we have
\begin{align}
a_{11}x_1^2+2a_{12}x_1x_2+a_{22}x_2^2&=a_{11}\left(x_1^2+2\frac{a_{12}}{a_{11}}x_1x_2+\frac{a_{22}}{a_{11}}x_2^2\right)\\
&=a_{11}\left[\left(x_1+\frac{a_{12}}{a_{11}}x_2\right)^2+\frac{a_{22}}{a_{11}}x_2^2-\frac{a_{12}^2}{a_{11}^2}x_2^2\right]\\
&=a_{11}\left[\left(x_1+\frac{a_{12}}{a_{11}}x_2\right)^2+\frac{a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}^2}{a_{11}^2}x_2^2\right].
\end{align}
Obviously, the constraint $a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}^2\ge 0$ would make the right-hand-side non-negative, i.e.,
$$
a_{11}x_1^2+2a_{12}x_1x_2+a_{22}x_2^2\ge 0.
$$

To sum up, $A$ is positive semi-definite if and only if
$$
a_{11}\ge 0,\quad a_{22}\ge 0,\quad a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}^2\ge 0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\b&c\end{pmatrix}\in M_2(\mathbb{R})$ be a symmetric matrix. By definition, $A$ is $\geq 0$ iff for every vector $z=[x,y]^T$, $f(z)=z^TAz=ax^2+2bxy+cy^2\geq 0$.

$\textbf{Proposition.}$ $A\geq 0$ iff $\{a\geq 0,c\geq 0,ac-b^2\geq 0\}$.

$\textbf{Proof}$. i) If $a\not= 0$, then $f(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $2$ in $x$; the NSC (necessary and sufficient condition for $A\geq 0$) is $a> 0$ and, for every $y$, $(b^2-ac)y^2\leq 0$, that is $a> 0,ac-b^2\geq 0$, that is $a>0,c\geq 0,ac-b^2\ge 0$.

ii) If $c\not= 0$, then  $f(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $2$ in $y$; in the same way as above, we obtain that the NSC is $a\geq 0,c>0,ac-b^2\geq 0$.

iii) If $a=c=0$, then the NSC is $b=0$ ($xy$ has not a constant signum), that is $a=c=0,ac-b^2\geq 0$.

We deduce the required equivalence. $\square$